# elasticsearch won't log slow queries anymore

Tags: elasticsearch

i had this working. not sure what changed.

in my elasticsearch.yml, the only things uncommented and updated are the following lines:

```
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn: 1ms
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info: 1ms
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug: 1ms
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace: 1ms
```

and my logging.yml has the following set:

```
es.logger.level: INFO
```

i've tried changing that value to 'DEBUG' and 'TRACE', but still doesn't work. 
yes, i've restarted my elasticsearch instance (several times)

what am i missing?

Comment: Can you share your version and overall config (number of nodes, rough number of indexes/shards/documents). Also when you say it won't log slow queries anymore, does the log file already exist? Is it empty?

Comment: sure - this is just a local test environment at the moment. so i'm running elasticsearch just on my machine. i have 6 indexes (one i'm using, others are marvel), 1 node, 100k documents, 317mb data, 10 shards, cpu is underwhelmed, ram is running hot (utilizing 7GB of 8GB total). the file does not exist. the strange thing is: it used to. i just can't get it to create new ones (new ones should be created each day).

Comment: Hi, did you eventually solved the problem? I'm having the same issue when migrating from 1.3 to 1.4. Thanks

Comment: i believe it worked when i changed the values in the original post to -1

Answer (score 2):

I'd try adding/changing your logging.yml file to the following:

```
additivity:
  index.search.slowlog: true
  index.indexing.slowlog: true
```

They both normally default to false

I'd try setting the fetch threshold too:

```
index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn: 1ms
index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.info: 1ms
index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug: 1ms
index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.trace: 1ms
```

Finally I'd also try setting everything to 0ms instead of 1ms. This should in effect log everything.

Comment: John, i tried your suggestions, restarted elasticsearch and tried running a query again. still no new slow log file created. there is an empty file that's always there and does seem to be used by elasticsearch (because i can't alter it) called elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog.log. but i believe the one i'm looking for is named with the date in it (and not empty of course). still not sure what happened as this did work before! weird.

Comment: can you add your logging.yml file to the question? and show all uncommented lines from elasticsearch.yml?